# Nagios - Powershell external script wrong output

Tags: powershell, nagios

I've created a ps1 script to monitor some webservices, and it is working.

I've defined the different exit codes with a message of CRITICAL, Warning and OK.

The Critical and warning are ok. The messages I've defined on the script appears on the check when it's critial or warning.

When the check is OK, the status message is the log of the file that is doing the test to the webservice.

The powershell script is calling a Testing tool that runs through a .cmd file that calls a .jar that executes the test, and write the output of the test to a txt file. And the powershell script will look for some patterns on the log and then define the critical, warning and OK.

```
if (Select-String -Path $path -pattern "successfully" -SimpleMatch)
{
Write-Host "Connection OK";
exit 0
}
elseif (Select-String -Path $path -pattern "not supported" -SimpleMatch)
{
Write-Host 'WARNING: Webservice not supported by monitoring';
exit 1
}
else {
Write-Host 'CRITICAL: Webservice unavailable';
exit 2
}
```

Anyone knows what can be wrong with the OK output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the string `"successfully"` is never to be found in the logs.. Please show us some examples of these logs.

Comment: there is no way to tell what the problem is without a sample of the data that includes the various tested values.